# CSS grid custom layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to build a CSS grid

I do not want to have space between item2 and item3, and want these items to be aligned on top of the container.

Is this possible with CSS only, without modifying the HTML structure?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item1 img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 115px;
}

.item2,
.item3 {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x115/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="item2">Element 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Element 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines to your `.grid-container` style:

```css
  grid-template-rows: 0fr 1fr;
  row-gap: 0;
```

Preview:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr 1fr;
  row-gap: 0;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.item1 img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 115px;
}

.item2,
.item3 {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x115/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="item2">Element 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Element 3</div>
</div>
```

---

Update:
If you need to add more elements, you can change the HTML structure and/or use pseudo element like `:before` and/or `:after`.

Don't forget to update your grid template.
See example below:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr 0fr 1fr;
  row-gap: 0;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3,
.item4 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item1 img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 115px;
}

.item2,
.item3,
.item4 {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x115/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="item2">Element 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Element 3</div>
  <div class="item4">Element 4</div>
</div>
```

If you need more flexible layout for unpredictable elements, try to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) instead of grid.

Comment: Thank you. But if I need to add a fourth element `<div class="item4">Element 4</div>`, it is pushed to the bottom of the container.

Comment: @superfive33 You need to mention that requirement in your question/problem description. However, I have updated my answer to solve that. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it. Not the best but it works using CSS only, without changing the HTML structure.

HTML

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x115/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="item2">Element 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Element 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  /*   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; */
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;

  grid-template-areas: 
    "left right"
    "left right";
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: left;
  /*   grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2; */
}

.item1 img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 115px;
}

.item2,
.item3 {
/*   grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1; */
  grid-area: right;
}

.item3 {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to fulfill your requirement.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
    align-items: start;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.item1 {
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 3;
}

.item1 img {
    width: 80px;
    height: 115px;
}

.item2,
.item3 {
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x115/000/fff">
    </div>
    <div class="item2">Element 2</div>
    <div class="item3">Element 3</div>
</div>
```